# name 'package_name' is not defined (did you mean 'PACKAGE_NAME'?)

Tags: bazel

I'm using bazel 0.24.0 to build an existing bzazel project.
After reading the bazel document , I change "PACKAGE_NAME" to "package_name()".
The following problem shows

"name 'package_name' is not defined (did you mean 'PACKAGE_NAME'?)" .

Also , "PACKAGE_NAME" is not working by showing the errors:
The value 'PACKAGE_NAME' has been removed in favor of 'package_name()', please use the latter (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/native.html#package_name).

Aare there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `native.package_name()`, not `package_name`.

Also note that the documentation is versioned. You are looking at the `master` version, but I think you want the 0.24.0 docs: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.24.0/skylark/lib/native.html#package_name